# How to display a value returned by .net core api?

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-core-webapi

I am building a c# forms application that is calling a .net core API

Code in the forms application is as follows

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

private async void btn_callAPI_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TopMost = false;

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44377/api/values/url/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var response = await client.GetAsync("1");
        
    MessageBox.Show(response.Content.ToString());
    client = new HttpClient();
}
```

The API I am calling is doing the following operation:

```
[HttpGet("url/{id}")]
public string Gets(int id)
{
    return "value2";
}
```

I want the message box to access the value returned by the API which in this case is a string `value2`.

How do I access the data returned by the API?

Comment: what do you mean by the date returned by the API ?

Comment: So what error you are getting??

Comment: System.Net.Http.StreamContent in the message box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("1");
string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```